# How to include an almost identical file in a separate namespace (for debugging purposes)

Tags: php, debugging, namespaces, include, namespace-organisation

I'm faced with the following PHP code problem:

At the moment my PHP code is not making use of any namespaces. I have made modifications to an include file `foobarinc.php` so that I now have the two versions `foobarinc-v1.php` (the old version) and `foobarinc-v2.php` (the new version). The include file has some functions (e.g. `foo()`) which is present in both files. At the moment `foobarinc-v2.php` has some bugs, so I need to debug my code with `foo()` from `fooinc-v1.php` (because at least I know it works) but I also need to call `foo()` from `foobarinc-v2.php` in other places. I don't want to change anything in the `foobarinc-v1.php file because I will be needing it as it is, but I would be willing to add a namespace to the file if necessary. Can I use PHP namespaces to achieve my purpose?

e.g. I would like to do:

main.php:

```
include("includes/foobarinc-v2.php");

function main() {

  hello(); // from main.php

  namespace myDebugNameSpace {

    include("includes/foobarinc-v2.php");

    $a = foo(); // foo() version 2

    outerNameSpace::bar($a); // bar() version 1

  }

  world(); // from main.php

  foo(); // foo() version 1

}

main();
```

How can I fix the above code to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to add in foobarinc-v1.php namespace as follows:

```
namespace foobarinc1;
```

foobarinc-v2.php almost the same:

```
namespace foobarinc2;
```

Main.php

```
include 'foobarinc-v1.php'; 
include 'foobarinc-v2.php';
use foobarinc1;
use foobarinc2;

foobarinc1->foo();
foobarinc2->foo();
```

You can find more here: 
http://php.net/manual/pl/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one more question, if I put those namespaces in the include files, then anyone using my include files (which I plan to distribute) would have to use use statements after the includes. Does this really make sense? Thanks.

Comment: It would get messy after a while especially with bigger projects. The solution would be using autoloader but I think in this case it would be an overkill.

Comment: But why do I have to create the namespace in the include file. Can't I import an include file that uses the default namespace and assign a namespace to the included file at the moment I am importing it?

Comment: I think it's not possible since server has to know exactly what to look for. And namespaces work for files with the same name. Can't think of any way to assign namespaces in such way, I might be wrong though.

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate. Namespaces could have been created as syntax constructs rather than as file-bound constructs. Any idea why PHP was designed like that?

Comment: Actually i think it's good the way it is. It takes one line of code in each file and all you need to do is 'use' it. And with autoloader u can get away with writing hundreds lines of 'use' statement.

Comment: OK, perhaps it has some advantages (less need to match braces and indent code). Anyways, I was wondering, for a large project, when would I put stuff in different packages as opposed to everything in one package. Well, I guess the answer here is the same as in Java where Java packages work exactly like PHP namespaces (although in Java one package can span multiple files. I guess this is possible with PHP also).